# How to reconnect to wifi via Ubuntu's default method

Tags: wireless, networking

I want to reconnect my wifi, but ideally something as simple as emulating the click on the wifi symbol on the top right. This is because I am behind a captive portal, and sometimes it times out, and it needs a reconnect in order to be available again, which I'd like to do via `cron`, but otherwise I really like gnome's utility.

Similar questions have been asked, but they all seem to resolve around some version of

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

That doesn't quite seem to do what I want. For example, after running `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` gnome doesn't even recognize that the wifi is disconnected (even though internet obviously doesn't work any more).

Is there a way to address whatever system it is that gnome is using?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If wireless is the only networking interface for your system, you could try `nmcli` to disable/enable your network, wifi should reconnect automatically in that case:

```
nmcli nm enable false && sleep 10 && nmcli nm enable true
```

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being quite simple:

```
nmcli nm wifi off
nmcli nm wifi on
```

No sleep required. To execute in `cron` I had to add a `sudo`.

My final script:

```
#!/bin/bash --
if ! nc -z -w 2 www.google.com 80
then
  echo "CONNECTION WEB: Can't reach the internet. Restarting wireless." | ts >> /var/log/wireless_log
  sudo /usr/bin/nmcli nm wifi off
  echo "CONNECTION WEB: Turned wifi off. Now turning back on." | ts >> /var/log/wireless_log
  sudo /usr/bin/nmcli nm wifi on
  echo "CONNECTION WEB: Turned wifi back on." | ts >> /var/log/wireless_log
fi
```

And added it to cron with

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/ensure_connection_to_web.sh
```